# Deploying Vue web app always causes caching issues for client

Tags: vue.js, caching, deployment

We are deploying a frontend Vue app based on a PHP backend. Always when we deploy a new version of the Vue app code, our client is stuck with the old code unless they do a hard refresh / clear cache / incognito mode.

How can you force a browser refresh of all cached content from the previous deployment?

Comment: If you're using webpack for bundling of the app, you can use the `AssetsPlugin` in conjunction with the `[contenthash]` placeholder in your output filenames. It will create a file called `assets.json` that you can read in your PHP backend and thus retrieve and output the path to the most current version of your CSS/JS assets.

Comment: We're using Vue CLI to build the app, which uses webpack internally of course. It is very strange where even a minimal change to Vue app, for example in the data object of the 'export default', does not propagate to the user without a hard refresh. It is probably unrelated to the backend solution.

Comment: It probably has to do with caching, and when you're using cache-busting via hashes in the asset filenames, you'll need to dynamically get the paths of the latest versions via the `assets.json` file in your backend.

Comment: [Check out this post](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vuejs-pwa-cache-busting-8d09edd22a31), may be useful.